# How do I install Stress load testing tool on CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, stress-testing, stress

[`stress`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stress) is a tool that imposes CPU, memory, I/O, or disk stress on an operating system, so you can test if your applications work under high load, e.g. when almost out of memory.

How do I install Stress on CentOS?

Installing on Ubuntu is trivial: `sudo aptitude install stress`. But I haven't found any package for CentOS, and what seems to be the homepage that "everyone" refers to returns 404 Not Found: http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stress is available for CentOS 6 from the EPEL repository.  You can find out more about the repository, including instructions for adding it to your `yum` configuration, at [the project's homepage](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: Thanks! Yes indeed, http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/stress.html  "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes" ServerFault says

Comment: I never knew there was a minimum wait time!  One learns something every day - thank you!

Comment: repoview has been retired. You can see information about `stress` [here](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/stress).