# How do i install stress on a CentOS7 server?

Tags: redhat, centos7, stress-testing

How do i install stress on a CentOS 7 server?

I've read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/551604/how-do-i-install-stress-load-testing-tool-on-centos) and I have `Package epel-release-7-7.noarch already installed and latest version`. When I `yum search stress` I get:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.hostingxtreme.com
 * epel: mirror.cs.pitt.edu
 * extras: mirrors.umflint.edu
 * updates: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
======================================================== N/S matched: stress ========================================================
httpress.x86_64 : HTTP stress & benchmark utility
```

That is not what i am looking for and man pages confirms:

```
httpress - High performance HTTP server stress & benchmark utility.
```

How can I install the stress tool on a centos7 headless server?

Comment: Have you tried `yum install httpress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the old EPEL 6 repo list [here](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/). Install with:

```
rpm -ivh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/stress-1.0.4-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: You should not be installing RPMs built for CentOS 6 on CentOS 7.

Comment: I would agree on the surface, but can you delineate a specific reason (outside of perhaps needed an outdated or deprecated dependency?)

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install stress
```

Comment: Fails now that CentOS 8 is out

Answer (score 0):

For Centos8 i did:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm 
yum install stress
```